# Error: There are some read requests waitng on finished stream

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have working in selenium test cases. below is my code

```
  browser.load('/sample/demo.html');
  browser.sleep(2000);
  element(By.id('upload')).sendKeys("D:\\files\\document.docx");
  browser.compareScreen(element(By.tagName('body')), 'image1');
```

By adding the above code, i can get the files properly. But i have facing the below error

```
 Error: There are some read requests waitng on finished stream
  Stack:
    Error: There are some read requests waitng on finished stream
        at module.exports.ChunkStream._end (node_modules\pngjs-image\node_modules\pngjs\lib\chunkstream.js:100:7)
        at module.exports.ChunkStream.end (node_modules\pngjs-image\node_modules\pngjs\lib\chunkstream.js:86:10)
        at Inflate.onend (_stream_readable.js:595:10)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
        at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
        at Inflate.emit (events.js:208:7)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL
```

I have tried to update the pngjs version to 3.3 above using `npm install pngjs  --save` but still same issue occurs.

Any one can suggest how to resolve this error. I couldn't get the details about this issue properly.